# Frequency response based on a transfer function

Tags: frequency, transfer-function

The transform function: $$T(s) = \frac{1-sRC}{1+sRC}$$
Polynomial form: $$-\frac{s-\frac{1}{RC}}{s + \frac{1}{RC}}$$
Since magnitudes of the zero *Sn = 1/RC* and pole *Sp = -1/RC* are equal,amplitude gain is 0. What about the phase? How does '-' sign affect the phase?

Without the minus: **Sn** i positive and real and has a \$\Pi\$ phase while the negative **Sp** has a \$0\$, at \$\omega=0\$.

As \$\omega\rightarrow\infty\$, \$\pi \rightarrow \pi/2\$ and \$ 0\rightarrow\pi/2\$. After subtracting the phases from zero and poles we have that phase changes from \$\pi\rightarrow0\$.

What does the minus affect?

Comment: For w=0 the phase is 0 and and approaches -180deg for rising frequencies. It is simply a first-order allpass.

Comment: If $z = x + j y$, what is the difference in phase compared to $-z = -x - j y$?

Comment: @LvW  Why is it -180deg, shouldn't it be +, since phase of -1 is +180?

Comment: @Arnfinn + \$\pi\$ ?

Comment: For stable systems the phase always goes to negative values (phase lag,falling chareacteristic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flSP6d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is a schematic of a first-order allpass.
As one can see, the phase starts at 0 deg (cap is open circuit) and goes to negative values (low pass response). For very large frequencies, the non-inv. input is grounded and we have negative unity gain (inverter) - equivalent to -180deg phase shift.

The transfer function is

**H(s)=(1+R/R)/(1+sRC) -R/R;
H(s)=(1-sRC)/(1+sRC)**